# Can I force extra fields to be required on asset upload

Tags: assets, control-panel

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to require additional fields be filled out while uploading an asset (mainly pdf's) in the admin control panel.  I know I can add meta data fields to an asset but the process seems to be upload the asset and then edit the assets to fill out those fields.  I could easily see a user uploading and not filling out the fields and for my requirements I need those fields to be filled out.

I am guessing I will have to create a plugin to handle this functionality but wanted to check if I am heading down the right path and if it is even possible.

Thanks